# I have a web page. I want to show blank page when user tries to see the source code of the web page. How can I do it?

Tags: html

I have a web page. I want to show the blank page when the user tries to see the source code of the web page. How can I do it?

Comment: You can't. The source of the page is sent to the browser to be rendered. You cannot affect the browser's ability to show the source of the page, since you already sent the source to the browser.

Why would you want to achieve this? If you are worried about exposing your code to your viewers, look at minifying and other obfuscation methods.

Answer (score 0):

When a user views a webpage in a browser, they are viewing the sourcecode - it is just being rendered by the browser differently than a text editor would render it.  So the only way to have the source code be hidden from the user is not to show it to them.  So have your website serve HTTP responses with no content.  In php, this would be:

```
<?php exit; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think I didn't understand. Are you suggesting me not to have any content on the webpage?

Comment: Yes.  That is the only way to have the user not be able to view the source code, because the source code is by nature public, at least the clientside source code is, that is, the html, css, and javascript.  The serverside code (php, python, ruby, etc.) should never be visible to anyone though.  If that is showing up for your users, that means you have an error in your apache or nginx configuration that needs to be addressed, in which case, could you provide more info on what your server software is and what is happening when you try to view a page?